# How to convert an indeterminate number of rgb occurrences in a string to hex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, hex, rgb, fireworks

Fireworks CS6 includes a panel that copies the CSS3 properties of the selected object.

However, the code is overly verbose and messy, so I'd like to write an extension in JavaScript that cleans it up.

I've done everything I need, except figuring out how to convert any number of rgb values in to their smaller hex code equivalents.

For example, a typical string it returns for gradients may include this:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(50% 0% -87deg, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,255,64) 28%, rgb(0,177,122) 40%, rgb(0,0,255) 68%, rgb(37,37,230) 76%, rgb(153,153,153) 100%); 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-87deg, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,255,64) 28%, rgb(0,177,122) 40%, rgb(0,0,255) 68%, rgb(37,37,230) 76%, rgb(153,153,153) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(-87deg, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,255,64) 28%, rgb(0,177,122) 40%, rgb(0,0,255) 68%, rgb(37,37,230) 76%, rgb(153,153,153) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,50% 0%,55% 100%, color-stop(0, rgb(0,0,0)), color-stop(0.28, rgb(0,255,64)), color-stop(0.4, rgb(0,177,122)), color-stop(0.68, rgb(0,0,255)), color-stop(0.76, rgb(37,37,230)), color-stop(1, rgb(153,153,153)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-87deg, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,255,64) 28%, rgb(0,177,122) 40%, rgb(0,0,255) 68%, rgb(37,37,230) 76%, rgb(153,153,153) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(-87deg, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(0,255,64) 28%, rgb(0,177,122) 40%, rgb(0,0,255) 68%, rgb(37,37,230) 76%, rgb(153,153,153) 100%);
border-color: rgb(198,34,221);
```

I already have a function that will convert r,g,b values to their hex equivalent, but I'm not sure how I would go about looping through the string and isolating the rgb components & converting each one.

Comment: Do be careful- HEX codes with Alpha components aren't handled nearly as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to capture this exact syntax - rgb with three decimal numbers without white spaces, then `string.replace(/rgb\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\)/g, yourFunction)` will do. First parameter will be entire rgb() sequence and next three will be R, G and B numbers. You will need to return new string to replace entire rgb().